# Start button on Windows 10 doesn't work and Microsoft Edge icon invisible

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, microsoft-edge

My Windows 10 computer recently got a problem and I don't know how. The first thing I noticed when I turned it on about a month ago was that the Microsoft Edge button was invisible. Later I saw that I could not left-click on the start button.

What should I do to fix these problems?

Comment: I experienced this problem for a long time. In my case, my computer was too slow and the Start menu would open after 2 or 3 minutes or not at all. How much RAM does your computer have? Simply meeting the Windows 10 requirements does not guarantee a usable interface. Does restarting into Safe Mode help at all? And when you say Edge is invisible, is it still invisible? Can you open at all?

Comment: I have been using Windows 10 for a long time, I know my computer can do it. How do I restart in Safe Mode? I can start up Edge but it takes ages, it has some bugs and lag that it usually doesn't and if I go into other programs I have to minimize all screens to get to Edge because the button only starts a new window.

Comment: In versions prior to Windows 8x, you could simply press F2 or F8 or F12 at startup and select "Safe Mode" or other startup options. With Windows 8x/10, etc... this method might not work. You can do the following instead: Go to Settings->Update & Security->Recovery->Advanced Startup->Restart Now. After your PC restarts, go to Troubleshoot->Advanced Options->Startup Settings->Restart. Then you should see the menu that was previously accessible on boot with a simple F8. By chance, is it just Edge or all your metro apps? Does IE start instantly? Have you tried running sfc /scannow from cmd?

Comment: Does this behavior exhibit itself while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I will try what you said but the computer has been working slow since this problem arised. I don't know what a metro app but I think I know what you mean. I can't click on what I search for. I can see results but not get to them. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you get to the startup thingy from the Control Panel? I can't get to Settings.

Comment: @InterLinked I found out how to get to Settings trough the Explorer. I booted up in Safe Mode but the Edge icon is still not visible. Internet Explorer opens up... I wouldn't say instantly but it doesn't take as much time as Edge. The computer decided to turn of at 48% of sfc /scannow... I will wait before I do that again, I am tired.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue on my Laptop after the first major Windows 10 update.

I couldn't find any useful solution so I waited until the next windows update and it resolved the issue. Are there any more windows updates pending that you could run?

Comment: I don't think I can open Windows Update. It seems like the problem has gone worse. Do you know how to get to settings through the explorer?

Comment: Can you right click on the start menu? If so you can select Control Panel through there.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the right-click. Thank you! Thank you! I will try Safe Mode now.